# Prove ~ is an equivalence relation on A

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Suppose that A is a non-empty subset of X and that a binary relation ~ on A is defined as follows:

$\quad$For all x,y $\in$ A, x~y if and only if there is a path in A from x to y. Then, for all x, y, and z $\in$A, prove
$$(i)x\text{~}x.$$
$$(ii)x\text{~}y \text{ then } y\text{~}x.$$
$$(iii)x\text{~}y \text{ and } y\text{~}z \text{ then } x\text{~}z.$$

In other words, prove ~ is an equivalence relation on A.

$(i)x\text{~}x$

$P:[0,1]\to$A , $\text{ }P(t)=x \text{ }\forall t$, that is constant path that we'll always find so $x\text{~}x$ is always going to hold.

$\therefore$ '~' is reflexive.

$(ii)x\text{~}y \text{ then } y\text{~}x.$

$P:[0,1]\to$A,  $P(0)=x$ ,  and $P(1)=y$ so that $x\text{~}y$. define $\overline P(t)=P(1-t)$

$\therefore$ a path from x to y exists, then we'll also have a path from y to x.

$\therefore$ If $x\text{~}y$, then $y\text{~}x$ and '~' is symmetric.

$(iii)x\text{~}y \text{ and } y\text{~}z \text{ then } x\text{~}z.$

$x\text{~}y$ so $P_1 [0,1] \to $ A s.t. $P_1 (0)=x$ and $P_1 (1)=y$

same thing for $y\text{~}z$, s.t. a path exists from y to z so $P_2 [0,1] \to $ A s.t. $P_2 (0)=y$ and $P_2 (1)=z$

Combining the two paths, $P_3 [0,1] \to $ A s.t.

$
P_3(1)=
\begin{cases}
 P_1(2t)&\text{if}\, 0\le t\le \frac{1}{2}\\
 P_2(2t-1)&\text{if}\, \frac{1}{2}\le t \le 1\\
\end{cases}
$

so that $P_3$ is a path from x to z in A

$\therefore$ $x\text{~}z$ and '~' is transitive

$\therefore$ $x\text{~}y$ and $y\text{~}z$, then $x\text{~}z$

$\therefore$ the relation is an equivalance relation.

This is what I have. I think I have this solution right but I would like to have it check. Thank you in advance!

Edit: Error found on the piecewise function founded by Mr. Custer and has been fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Looks good except you made an error when you combined the two paths.

Comment: Corollary. A connected, locally path-connected space is a path-connected space. (The Topologists' Sine Curve is an example of a connected space which is not path-connected.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part $(iii)$, you want $p_3(t)=\begin{cases} p_1(2t), 0\le t\le1/2\\p_2(2t-1),1/2\le t\le1\end{cases}$.